# Azure ARM Template (JSON) Self-Reference

Tags: json, azure, azure-rm-template

I'm creating some default "drag and drop" templates for our developers, and one section is the required tags. Most of the tags reference a variable: nice and easy. But one wants to reference the resource itself and I cannot figure out a way to it. Does anyone have any suggestions?

The tag itself is called "Context" and it's value should be the "type" of the resource it is in, e.g. "Microsoft.Web/serverfarms". This is desired to aid with billing. Obviously I could either create a different template per resource type (not ideal considering the number of different resources) or rely on the devs to update the field manually (not ideal either as relying on them to add the tags manually hasn't worked so far in a lot of cases), but I am trying to automate it.

Extrapolating from the [variables('< variablename >')] function I did try [resources('type')] but Azure complained that "resources is not a valid selection". I thought it might have complained that it couldn't tell which resource to look at, but it didn't get that far. Internet searches have not turned up anything useful so far.

Answer (score 0):

I can't find a way to do this cleanly either (I hope someone corrects me though! This is a topic for us too). The `reference` and `resourceId` functions look promising, but both are unavailable inside of the `resources` block, would require some parsing, and also require the api version, which you probably also need to vary by resource and so you're just back to where you started. ARM won't even let you use a variable for the resource type property(probably a good thing), so that option is out too.

As such, you'll either have to live with your team having to replace that chunk of text manually or pursue some alternative.

The simplest thing that comes to mind would be to write a script in a language that understands JSON. That script reads the template, adds the tag to the resource, then saves the template again.

A similar approach would be to do it after the resources are deployed by writing a script that loops through all resources and making sure they have the tag. You can use automation to schedule this on a regular basis if you're concerned about it being missed. If you're deploying the templates using a script, you could add it in that script too.

There's some things you probably do with nested templates, but you probably wouldn't be making anyone's life easier or making the process more reliable.

Comment: We have decided to go manual for now. I did look at nested templates, but it would basically still require a separate variable per resource group. We do already use a PowerShell script to check for missing / null value tags. We'll just amend that for now. It's a shame that we cannot seem to make it self-reference.

Answer (score 0):

This could be achievable potentially through some powershell [specifically around Resource and Resource Group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/set-azresource?view=azps-3.2.0).  Would need to run a Get-AzResource either at the subscription or potentially just the resource group level.  Then pull the ResourceType field from the object return and use a Set-AzResource command passing in the ResourceID from above and the new tag mapped to the returnedResourceType field.